# Getting the id of an html on mouseover with only javascript (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

My question is this, if I have an Text html element that looks like...

```
<a id='1' onmouseover="changeImage('setname/setnumber')">Cardname</a>
```

Can I retrieve the id (in this case 1) on a mouseover event so that I may use it in javascript to do something else with it.

Not sure if I can do this, but I'm hoping I can. What I have is a bit of javascript code that is taking data from an xml document.  I have a list of 500+ cards that I have parsed through and stored by categories that are used often.  Here are the relevant functions as they apply to my question.

```
var Card = function Card(cardName, subTitle, set, number, rarity, promo, node)
{
    this.cardName = cardName;
    this.subTitle = subTitle;
    this.set = set;
    this.number = number;
    this.rarity = rarity;
    this.promo = promo;
    this.node = node;
}
```

Where node is the position within the list of cards, and due to the formatting of the document which I started with contains each card alphabetically by name, rather than numbered logically within sets.

```
Card.prototype.toLink = function()
{
    var txt = "";
    this.number;
    if (this.promo == 'false')
    {
    var image = this.set.replace(/ /g, "_") + '/' + this.number;
    txt += "<a id='" + this.node + "' onmouseover=changeImage('" + image + "')>";
    txt += this.toString() + "</" + "a>";
    }
    else 
    {
    var image = this.set.replace(/ /g, "_") + '/' + this.rarity + this.number;
    var txt = "";
    txt += "<a id='" + this.node + "' onmouseover=changeImage('" + image + ')>";
    txt += this.toString() + "</a>";
    }
    return txt; 
}
```

Here is what I am using to populate a list of cards, with names that upon hovering over will display a card image.

```
function populateList () {
    for (i = 0; i<cards.length; i++)
    document.getElementById('myList').innerHTML += '<li>'+cards[i].toLink()+</li>;
}
```

What I am trying to do is retrieve the id of the element with the onmouseover event so that I can retrieve everything that is not being saved to a value.
I realized I can pass the id as part of the changeImage function as a temporary workaround, though it involves rewriting my toLink function and my changeImage function to include a second argument.  As a married man, I've enough arguments already and could do with one less per card.

In summary, and I suppose all I needed to ask was this, but is there a way using only javascript and html to retrieve the id of an element, onmouseover, so that I may use it in a function. If you've gotten through my wall of text and code I thank you in advance and would appreciate any insights into my problem.

Answer (score 3):

> if I have an Text html element that looks like...
>
> `<a id='1' onmouseover="changeImage('setname/setnumber')">Cardname</a>`
>
> Can I retrieve the id (in this case 1) on a mouseover event so that I may use it in javascript to do something else with it.

Yes, if you can change the link (and it looks like you can):

```
<a id='1' onmouseover="changeImage('setname/setnumber', this)">Cardname</a>
```

Note the new argument `this`. Within `changeImage`, you'd get the `id` like this:

```
function changeImage(foo, element) {
    var id = element.id;
    // ...
}
```

Looking at your code, you'd update this line of `toLink`:

```
txt += "<a id='" + this.node + "' onmouseover=changeImage('" + image + ', this)>";
```

Of course, you could also just put the `id` in directly:

```
txt += "<a id='" + this.node + "' onmouseover=changeImage('" + image + ', " + this.node + ")>";
```

And then `changeImage` would be:

```
function changeImage(foo, id) {
    // ...
}
```

I didn't use quotes around it, as these IDs look like numbers. But if it's not reliably a number, use quotes:

```
txt += "<a id='" + this.node + "' onmouseover=changeImage('" + image + ', '" + this.node + "')>";
```

Comment: Ok, honestly that is between where I was and where I want to eventually be, I was contemplating adding this.node as a second argument, but your answer will work much better for me going forward, and answers my question.  Many thanks.

Comment: Ok, so your answer led me to another problem, wonder if you know what might be causing this issue.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423155/strange-bug-when-trying-to-add-an-argument-to-a-javascript-function-call-from-wi