# Strange bug when trying to add an argument to a javascript function call from within html

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so I'm not sure what it is that I'm missing here, but I'm having a strange issue with this bug.

```
Card.prototype.toLink = function()
{
    var txt = "";
    if (this.promo == 'false')
    {
        var image = this.set.replace(/ /g, "_") + '/' + this.number;
        txt = txt + "<a id='" + this.node + "' onmouseover=changeImage('" + image + "')>" + this.toString() + "</a>";
    }
    else 
    {
        var image = this.set.replace(/ /g, "_") + '/' + this.rarity + this.number;
        txt = txt + "<a id='" + this.node + "' onmouseover=changeImage('" + image + "')>" + this.toString() + "</a>";
    }
    return txt; 
}
```

The above code produces a link to a card with the proper structure

```
<a id='node' onmouseover='changeImage('set/number')> this.toString() </a>
```

But if I add in some extra text, as part of an existing string in the additions, I get a seriously borked tag

If I change the function to

```
Card.prototype.toLink = function()
{
    var txt = "";
    if (this.promo == 'false')
    {
        var image = this.set.replace(/ /g, "_") + '/' + this.number;
        txt = txt + "<a id='" + this.node + "' onmouseover=changeImage('" + image + "' , this)>" + this.toString() + "</a>";
    }
    else 
    {
        var image = this.set.replace(/ /g, "_") + '/' + this.rarity + this.number;
        txt = txt + "<a id='" + this.node + "' onmouseover=changeImage('" + image + "' , this)>" + this.toString() + "</a>";
    }
    return txt; 
}
```

I end up with a tag that looks like this.

```
<a id='node' this)="" ,="" onmouseover="changeImage("set/number"> this.toString() </a>
```

Maybe I just need an extra pair of eyes on this to see what might be breaking it, but something is not jiving with me.  If anyone has any idea why adding part of an expression like this may be breaking it, please let me know.

What I want the output to look like is, where the only variables in the final code are represented by anything in []

```
<a id='[node]' onmouseover="changeImage([image], this)"> [this.toString()] </a>
```

Edit: I am currently trying to view the html file that's created with Firefox, if that could help to answer anything.

Answer (score 0):

Adding part of an expression? You don't seem to be adding part of an expression.

```
onmouseover=changeImage('" + image + "' , this)>"
```

This code is adding, as can be seen by the highlighting on your question, a string to your code.

```
"' , this)>"
```

I presume this is your issue. Have you tried:

```
 txt = txt + "<a id='" + this.node +
       "' onmouseover=changeImage('" + image + "' ,'"+ this + "')>" +    
       this.toString() + "</a>";
```

Comment: I want the word this in my output, that is the problem.  What I want the output to look like is 

<a id='[node]' onmouseover="changeImage([image], this)"> this.toString() </a>